# Error while using .copyItemAtPath

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to copy a file (.plist) to a new directory but I am getting an error saying : Extra argument "error" in call. My code is below.
I searched apple's swift documentation. I guess .copyItemAtPath code changed and I need to use throws but I cant implement throws apperantly.

```
var folder = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(folderName, ofType: folderType)

//this is where i get error

NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(folder, toPath: folderPath, error:nil)
print("Coppied")
```

Comment: What do you mean by you can't implement throws ?

Comment: I was referring to this site: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Swift2 you need to do something like this:

```
    do{
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(folder, toPath: folderPath) 
        print("Coppied")
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.localizedDescription);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to solve the problem. I wil finish the project and let you know if it all works